# What is the Von Neuman bottleneck?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

What is the Von Neuman bottleneck and how does functional programming reduce its effect? Can someone explain in a **simple** way through a **practical and comprehensive example** that shows, for instance, the advantage of using Scala over Java, if there is any?

More importantly, why is avoiding imperative control-structures and preferring functions so significant to improving performance? Ideally, an actual coding  example that explains how a problem solved **with** a function and **without** one is affected by the Von Neuman bottleneck would be very helpful.

Comment: The two are completely unrelated. The Von Neumann Bottleneck refers to system throughput at a level *waaay* below the level of programming languages (i.e. hardware architecture).

Comment: Voting to close. The Von Neumann Bottleneck is defined and explained elsewhere on the internet; no need for StackOverflow to refer to Wikipedia. The second part ("How is Scala better than Java") is primarily opinion-based. Plus, as mentioned by @JaredSmith, the two parts of the question have nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Scala will not necessarily fix your performance problems, even if you use functional programming.

More importantly, there are many causes of poor performance, and you don't know the right solution without profiling.

The [von Neumann Bottleneck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture#Von_Neumann_bottleneck) has to do with the fact that, in a von Neumann architecture, the CPU and memory are separate and therefore the CPU often has to wait for memory. Modern CPUs solve this by caching memory. This isn't a perfect fix, since it requires the CPU to guess correctly about which memory it needs to cache. However, high-performance code makes it easy for the CPU to guess correctly by structuring data efficiency and iterating over data linearly (i.e. good [data locality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference)).

Scala can simplify parallel programming, which is probably what you are looking for. This is not directly related to the von Neumann Bottleneck.

Even so, Scala is not automatically the answer if you want to do parallel programming. There are several reasons for this.

1. Java is also capable of parallel programming, and has many types of parallel collections for that purpose.
2. Java 8 Streams are Java's answer to Scala's parallel collections. They can be used for functional programming.
3. Parallel programming is not guaranteed to improve performance, and can make a program slower on small data sets, due to setup costs.

There is one case where you are correct that Scala overcomes the von Neumann Bottleneck, and that is with big data. When the data won't fit easily on a single machine, you can store the data on many machines, such as a Hadoop cluster. Hadoop's distributed filesystem is designed to keep data and CPUs close together to avoid network traffic. The easiest way to program for Hadoop is currently with Apache Spark in Scala. Here are some [Spark examples](https://spark.apache.org/examples.html); as of Spark 2.x, the Scala examples are much simpler than the Java examples.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question of whether or not a bad question can have a good answer +1.